# How to (simply and clearly) make a set of sync functions in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, synchronization

How to simply and clearly make a set of sync functions in Node.js, changing data amongst them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shall install and use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, in-which we shall use **series** method

```
var async = require('async');    

var data=0; //data to be interchanged amongst the series of functions

async.series([
    function(callback) {
            //task 1
            data=10;
            callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
            //task 2
            data=data-5;
            callback();
    }
]);

console.log(data); //5
```